# HttpResponse in Webapi controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web api controller as follows:

```
[HttpPost]    
public HttpResponseMessage PostMethod(string filename)    
{
    Stream downloadStream = BL.method(fileName);    
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();    
    response.content= new StreamContent(downloadStream);    
    return response;    
}
```

When I try to call the above method using fiddler I am getting an exception saying

> 'downloadStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'.

Can the stream be set in response and sent? Is there any modification for the above code?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your stream. Without knowing how stream is generated it is difficult to say. If you replace `BL.method(fileName);` with just loading the file yourself using `FileStream` this should work (I just tested it myself).

On the side note, there are a few problems with your approach:

1. You use POST. Since you are not changing anything GET is better.
2. You are not setting `ContentType` header so client can have problem using resource
3. You are not disposing the stream so this stream could stay in limbo and generally not good.

Comment: Actually I cannot replace BL.method(fileName); with filestream because I am streaming this file rite from database .I am fetching the stream from db by giving its fileName.So is there any solution for that?

Comment: there seems to be the bug in there not in Web API.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PushStreamContent, maybe by not buffering the file in memory, you might avoid your timeout.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostMethod(string filename)
    {
        Stream downloadStream = BL.method(fileName);
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent((responseStream, httpContent, tc) => {
                                                     downloadStream.CopyTo(responseStream);
                                                     responseStream.Close();
                                                 }, "application/octet-stream");

        return response;
    }
```